# Prevent page from going top when clicking on list item

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS.
I am using select2 component with angular. when I select list item form the list then page goes at Top position then again i have to scroll down again. please help me how i solve this problem.

```
<html>
<body>
.....
....
....
....  //scrolled down and selected the item 
<table style="width:100%">
<tr ng-repeat="inneritem in workflow" >
    <td >         
     <input type="text" ui-select2="selectuiOptions"     
     ng-model="process_added" ng-click="selectProcessChange()">
   </td>        
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular js code:

```
$scope.selectuiOptions =
 {
  data:$scope.processes,    
  formatResult : processList1,
  formatSelection : processList1,   
};  

function processList1(processElement) {
return "<img class='flag' src='../images/p.png'/>
 <div class='h5' style='display:inline-block;padding-left:15px'>"+processElement.name + "</div>
 <div style='padding-left:30px' class='h5'>
 <span class='icon-code-updated icon-doc-missing' style='display:inline-block'></span>"
 + processElement.status+"</div>";
        }

$scope.workflow[];
$scope.selectProcessChange =function(selected_Process){     
            $scope.workflow.push(selected_Process); 
};
```

Comment: What is "select2 component"? You should at least provide a link and some of your own code.

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: you can consider as Dropdown

Comment: works fine in source demos, so obviously you have done something different than in demos. You need to provide code with your questions and along with code a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net that replicates problem would also help a lot. Without code...you are not going to get any assistance

Comment: `Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.`

Comment: @prashantbirajdar please provide a plunker or fiddle with an example.

Comment: When you say top position, do you mean the select options shows the top item , or do you mean the page scrolls to the top ?

Comment: @RobSedge page scrolls to the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer. after looking this i was surprised how is it happened just i changed the select2.css file which

**Previously**

```
.select2-container {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    /* inline-block for ie7 */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**after change:**

```
.select2-container {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* inline-block for ie7 */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

it's working properly..Thank you all

Comment: Hmm kind of tough to trigger everybody with a bounty of +50 when the error was in code you did not provide. Sorry just my 50c.

Comment: but i never thought about this code will take effect to the scroll up .

Comment: Hmm I see. But nicer would be to do `<td><div style="position=relative">
     <input ui-select2="..."/></div>` which should also work and you do not have to adjust 'library code'. Then select2 is absolutely positioned **relative to the position of the div** which would be good for every table cell.

Comment: once you write in LIB no need to write again n again in code.

Comment: thats true, but when there is an update of this library you have to remember that custom fix and do it again. But I am silent now as you solved this to your satisfaction ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
angular.module('module').value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop);
```

it helped me

Comment: i tried this one. but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest two things that you can try, but without a plunkr or jsfiddle, it's really just a guess. However, I'm not aware of anything else that will cause scrolling.

### 1) turn off autoscroll

```
module.config
(
    [
        '$anchorScrollProvider',
        function(asp)
        {
            asp.disableAutoScrolling();
        }
    ]
)
```

### 2) turn off auto route reload

```
$routeProvider.when
(
    '/yourRoute',
    {
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }
);
```